# How to manage sub-domains on Ubuntu

Tags: dns

I have an Ubuntu server with the following domains:

sub-staging.example.com
sub.example.com

While testing the site via mobile, I noticed the phone would force the url to:

```
www.sub.example.com
```

Which would show page not found, DNS error.

So to fix this I added a CNAME record to the main domain (hosted elsewhere on Cpanel) and pointed the CNAME: www.sub.example.com to sub.example.com.

This works... except for one thing.

My staging domain is loading instead of the sub.example.com domain.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was easy to solve, looking at the /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf file I note that I had forgotten to add the alias to www.sub.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sub.example.com
   ServerAlias www.sub.example.com   <---- I had forgotten this
   Redirect permanent / https://sub.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin someone@example.com
        ServerName sub.example.com
        ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
```